# Library gtkmm not found by the compiler, but installed

Tags: compiler-errors, g++, homebrew, macos-mojave, gtkmm

I want to compile a test programm in C++ with the library gtkmm included. During the compilation, the library is not found. 
I am on macos mojave. I installed gtkmm with homebrew.

The file gtkmm.h is here: `/usr/local/Cellar/gtkmm/2.24.5_2/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm.h`

I tried to write in my code: `#include "/usr/local/Cellar/gtkmm/2.24.5_2/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm.h"`

But then the compiler doesn't find the headers which are in the file `gtkmm.h`.

The brew doctor tells everything seems to be ok.

Here is the code:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Gtk::Main app(argc, argv);

    Gtk::Window fenetre;

    Gtk::Main::run(fenetre);

    return 0;
}
```

On the terminal, I write:

```
g++ test.cpp -o Fenetre `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

And it answers:

> ```
> Package gtkmm-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
> Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtkmm-3.0.pc'
> to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
> No package 'gtkmm-3.0' found
> test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'gtkmm.h' file not found
> "#include <gtkmm.h>
>          ^~~~~~~~~
> 1 error generated.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Simply because of gtkmm version 2.4 is not the same than gtkmm version 3! You have installed version 2.4 but compiling with version 3 which seems not to be present in your environment.